# php Date increment from array date

Tags: php, date

Having trouble getting a way to increment a string date by one day.

So it starts off with `30/01/2001` for example.

```
$linedata[8] = 30/01/2001;
```

Then I use date parse form format.

```
$thetime = date_parse_from_format("j/n/Y",$linedata[8]);
```

The return is in array. Is it possible to increment the date from this array or should i be parsing the date with a different function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `date_parse_from_format()` as that just gives you a lot of date parts which requires you modifying the appropriate ones and then reassembling them. You also have issues with leap years and working with the last day of the month.

You want to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which gives you a DateTime object which is easy to work with and handles things like leap years and the number of days in a month:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("j/n/Y", '30/01/2001');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/201147)

Comment: Looks neat but i'm returned an error, Fatal error: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object ..... is it a php version issue?

Comment: What version are you using? [This will work with PHP 5.3+](http://3v4l.org/Xfo94)

Comment: version is 5.4.22. i just checked the modify function and should be fine as 5.2.0

Comment: This should work. What actual date are you using in your test? It's possible the format we are providing the function is wrong.

Comment: Is your `$linedata[8]` defined as `30/01/2001` or as `'30/01/2001'`? The first is 30 divided by 1 divided by 2001; the second is a human-formatted date string

Comment: When I echo, its only shown as 30/01/2001 . No apostrophes. Actual date example is 30/06/2011 , so the format should be correct.

Comment: There's something wrong with how that date is being provided to `DateTime::createFromFormat()` as that is [the only way  to create this error](https://eval.in/201155).

Comment: Been gradually working through what could cause my problem. https://eval.in/201169 this is from having white space in the line. https://eval.in/201170 and this is if the array value is blank which I suspect is what has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the date like this:

```
$thetime["day"]++;
```

or

```
$thetime["day"] = $thetime["day"] + 1;
```

then you can get the incremented date like this

```
$idate = $thetime["day"]."/".$thetime["month"]."/".$thetime["year"];
```

Comment: What happens on February 28th in a non-leap year? Or January 31st?This totally breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This would work (providing $linedata[8] contains a date):

```
$thetime = date('j/n/Y', strtotime($linedata[8] . ' +1 day'));
```

Comment: That date format is not one [strtotime can work with](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).